# How can I solve conflict issue installing pymc3?

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, dependencies, pymc3

I've tried to install pymc3 but the dependency issue still remained.

```
C:\Users\sykan>conda install -c conda-forge pymc3
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides vc 10.* needed by python-3.4.5-0

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.11.* , which can be installed;
└─ pymc3 is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ pymc3 [3.0|3.0rc2|...|3.6] would require
   │  └─ python [2.7* |>=2.7,<2.8.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.0|3.0rc2|3.0rc4|3.0rc6] would require
   │  └─ python 3.4*  but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ python 3.4.5 would require
   │     │  └─ vc 10.* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   │     └─ python 3.4.5 would require
   │        └─ vs2010_runtime, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   ├─ pymc3 [3.0|3.0rc2|...|3.5.rc1] would require
   │  └─ python [3.5* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.0|3.1|...|3.5.rc1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.6* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.11.2|3.11.3|...|3.6] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.11.2|3.11.3|3.11.4|3.11.5] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.11.2|3.11.3|3.11.4|3.11.5] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.2|3.3|3.4.1|3.5|3.6] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 3.10.0 would require
   │  └─ theano-pymc 1.0.11  but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2] would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2] would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     └─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2] would require
   │        └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 3.11.0 would require
   │  └─ theano-pymc 1.1.0  but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     └─ theano-pymc [1.1.0|1.1.2] would require
   │        └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.11.1|3.11.2] would require
   │  └─ theano-pymc 1.1.2  but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.0.11|1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     ├─ theano-pymc [1.1.0|1.1.2], which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │     ├─ theano-pymc 1.1.2 would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     └─ theano-pymc 1.1.2 would require
   │        └─ scipy >=0.14,<1.8  but there are no viable options
   │           ├─ scipy [0.19.1|1.0.0|...|1.5.3] would require
   │           │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │           ├─ scipy [1.1.0|1.2.0|...|1.7.3] would require
   │           │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │           ├─ scipy [1.3.1|1.3.2|...|1.7.3] would require
   │           │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │           ├─ scipy [1.5.2|1.5.3|...|1.7.3] would require
   │           │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │           ├─ scipy [1.7.2|1.7.3] would require
   │           │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │           ├─ scipy [0.19.1|1.0.0|...|1.2.1] would require
   │           │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │           └─ scipy [0.19.1|1.0.0|1.0.1|1.1.0] would require
   │              └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 3.11.2 would require
   │  └─ gxx_linux-64 9.* , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   ├─ pymc3 [3.7|3.8|3.9.1|3.9.2|3.9.3] would require
   │  └─ theano >=1.0.4  but there are no viable options
   │     ├─ theano 1.0.4 would require
   │     │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     ├─ theano [1.0.4|1.0.5] would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     ├─ theano [1.0.4|1.0.5] would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     ├─ theano [1.0.4|1.0.5] would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     ├─ theano 1.0.5 would require
   │     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │     └─ theano 1.0.5 would require
   │        └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 [3.9.2|3.9.3] would require
   │  └─ contextvars, which requires
   │     └─ python >=3,<3.7  but there are no viable options
   │        ├─ python [3.5.1|3.5.2|...|3.5.6] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │        ├─ python 3.4.5, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │        ├─ python 3.4.5, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   │        ├─ python [3.6.0|3.6.1|...|3.6.9] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   │        └─ python [3.6.0a3|3.6.0a4|...|3.6.0rc1] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pymc3 3.9.3 would require
   │  └─ theano >=1.0.5 , which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
   └─ pymc3 3.11.4 would require
      └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

Here's what I tried before this :

1. conda install -c conda-forge pymc3
2. conda create -c conda-forge -n pymc_env "pymc>=5"
   conda activate pymc_env
3. pip install --upgrade theano-pymc

All tries I've done didn't work. Still have dependency issues. I want to know what's the matter and how to solve it. Thanks.